# How to parse this json data in Delphi 10.3?

Tags: json, delphi

I'm new to Delphi and I learn it at the moment.
I have this peace of code. It works very well.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jValue : TJSONValue;
  JsonArray: TJSONArray;
begin

  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  jValue := RESTResponse1.JSONValue;

  // Ist this the right way? --> JsonArray := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(jValue.ToString) as TJSONArray;

  MemoContent.Lines.Add('Zitat des Tages:');
  MemoContent.Lines.Add(jValue.ToString);

end;
```

The output is the following JSON String:

```
Zitat des Tages:\n
{"951":{"zitat":"\nWo ein Wille ist, ist auch ein Holzweg.\n\n","autor":"André Brie"},"timestamp":"2020 09 03 19:21:36"}
```

Now, I want to parse the JSON Object to write zitat, autor to my memo. But I don't know to do that. I've read a lot, but I don't understand to get my string into an array and then to parse it to the elements.

Any tipps or some help from you profies?

Thanks for help.

Comment: The `TRESTResponse.JSONValue` is already parsed for you.  You do not need to convert it to a `string` just to re-parse it yourself.  Change this: `JsonArray := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(jValue.ToString) as TJSONArray;` to this: `JsonArray := jValue as TJSONArray;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will probably do the parsing you need:

```
    uses System.JSON;
    
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        JSonData   : String;
        JSonObject : TJSonObject;
        JSonValue  : TJSonValue;
        Zitat      : String;
    begin
        JSonData   := '{"951":{"zitat":"\nWo ein Wille ist, ist auch ein Holzweg.\n\n","autor":"André Brie"},"timestamp":"2020 09 03 19:21:36"}';
        JSonObject := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(JSonData) as TJSonObject;
        try
            JSonValue := JSonObject.Get('951').JSONValue;
            Zitat     := JSonValue.GetValue<string>('zitat');
        finally
            JSonObject.Free;
        end;
        ShowMessage(Zitat);
    end;
```

You should add more testing to handle cases where JSON data is malformed or doesn't contain the required data.